# I see all kinds of things on top of users profile images. What's going on?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Can anyone please explain these hats? What if someone has all the hats? Is there an improvement in someone's profile or something else?

Comment: Why does the title of this question keep changing all the time if it is already closed? Was your question not answered by the existing answer and the linked duplicates?

Answer (score 5):

There are no new badges, only hats (and masks) and they are **temporary**:

> #### What happens after January 4th?
>
> After January 4th, the sites go back to normal and all hats disappear. This is meant to be a fun end-of-year celebration, not a permanent addition to the site.

([source: the Winter Bash FAQ](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/faq))

---

> What if someone has all the badges? Is there an improvement in someone's profile or something else?

That someone will then probably win Winter Bash, but there's nothing permanent here either, except that the winners of Winter Bash will probably be mentioned in the closing blog post. The [leaderboards](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/leaderboard) will be gone too (except that you can probably find copies in the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20200924015438/https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)).

Answer (score 3):

This is an event that happens every year. You do some activity on the website and try to obtain as many hats as you want, and you can also not participate in this event.

No one actually gains anything from collecting all the hats. It's just for fun.

Comment: "No one actually gains anything" is not 100% accurate. The top collectors are mentioned in the official blog post when winter bash is over, and gain lots of exposure, which can lead to lots of actual site reputation.